# how to receive push notification when app is turned off?

Tags: iphone, ios4, notifications, push, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing a push notification functionality for my app and everything is running smoothly except for one case.

The situation is this:
When the app is off (not running in background either) and the user receives a push notification. The user hits "Close" and then later on decides to go to the app. I would like my app delegate to know the push notification that was received earlier however, I don't know how to check that. I know that I can have a function call in my didLaunch... but that works when the user decides to hit the "View" button instead of "Close".

Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, the answer is don't bother. You can never guarantee that the alert was received, so unfortunately you'll run into problems later if you rely on this. apns doesn't guarantee a device will receive a payload.